# Shut down gas for heat boiler but did not shut down electricity

Tags: boiler

new to this house, didn't see the shut off switch when i shut down boiler two months ago.  now i have found what looks like shut off switch, have I done any damage to the unit?

Comment: How did you shut down the boiler without using the switch?

Comment: IT's a very 100 year old system. I shut it off earlier by turning off the gas. Hopefully it'll start up in the fall.

Answer (score 1):

If you just shut off the gas without shutting off the electrical, it *shouldn't* damage the system.  Basically the thermostat(s) will continue to call for heat, the boiler will try to fire up and fail, then the boiler *should* give up and enter lockout. The boiler has safeguards built in to handle a lack of gas, which *should* prevent damage to the system.